# Font for Text on Hover

Tags: html

total new to this. Was trying to design a website on Wix but they do not have text color change on hover.

I searched and found this HTML Code online, but I couldn't get the font to change, it keeps defaulting me back to Arial. Can anyone shed some light on whats wrong with the font portion? (hover works great)

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine">


<style>
  
  p,
  p:hover {
    font-family: 'Tangerine', sans;
    font-size: 32px;
    text-align: center;
    transition: text-shadow 0.5s, color .5s ease-in-out;
  }
  p:hover {
    transition: color 0.5s, text-shadow .5s ease-in-out;
    color: yellow;
    text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #000, 1px -1px 0 #000, -1px 1px 0 #000, 1px 1px 0 #000;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  }
  
</style>



<p>
  TEXT GOES HERE
</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a hilarious twist, it's your HTML comments that are breaking the CSS.

HTML comment syntax: `<!-- comment -->`

CSS comment syntax: `/* comment */`

I tidied up a bit of your redundant code, too. Here it is working:

```css
p {
  /*This will be executed for whether the text is hovered or not*/
  font-family: 'Tangerine', sans;
  font-size: 32px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: text-shadow .5s, color .5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
p:hover {
  /*This will only be executed on mouse over*/
  color: yellow; /*The color of the text*/
  text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #000, 1px -1px 0 #000, -1px 1px 0 #000, 1px 1px 0 #000;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine">
<!--Imports google's "Tangerine" font-->

<p>
  TEXT GOES HERE
</p>
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure to add correcty the font-family on the p:hover block of the code, check the snippet.

Greetings.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine"><!--Imports google's "Tangerine" font-->

<style>

p, p:hover{<!--This will be executed for whether the text is hovered or not-->

font-family: 'Verdana';

font-size: 32px;

text-align:center;

transition: text-shadow 0.5s , color .5s ease-in-out;

}

p:hover{<!--This will only be executed on mouse over-->

transition: color 0.5s , text-shadow .5s ease-in-out;

color: yellow;<!--The color of the text-->

text-shadow:

-1px -1px 0 #000,

1px -1px 0 #000,

-1px 1px 0 #000,

1px 1px 0 #000;

-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-family: 'Verdana';

}

</style>

<p>

TEXT GOES HERE

</p>
```

Comment: Your code does not solve the poster's problem of getting Google's "Tangerine" web font showing. I posted an answer that fixes the broken CSS.

Comment: I understand he wants to change the font of p on hover

Comment: Thanks! This helped me :)

Comment: @Demonas This is poor advice - you don't need to specify the `font-family` again in a hover state. The `:hover` state should only contain the differences from the original style (which is why on my answer, it only includes `color` and `text-shadow`).